# If I use a struct to carry argc and argv, how do I assign the address argv to a variable inside the structure?

Tags: c++, struct, pass-by-reference, argv

I have defined some structure above main as:

```
struct arguments
{
   int c;
   char *v[];
};
```

now I want to do this in main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    arguments arg;

    arg.c = argc;
    arg.v = argv; /* error: incompatible types in assignment of 'char** to char* [0]' */
}
```

So, I do not fully understand what I am doing, but instinctively I remade the structure such that the line `char *v[];` is instead `char **v[];` however, this means when I pass by reference my structure `arg`, if I want to dereference and get the value of `arg.v[0]`, which will be the program name, I now have to do `*arg.v[0]` and this no longer works for `*arg.v[1]`.

I have a function such as:

```
void argument_reader(arguments &arg)
{
   cout << "Number of arguments: " << arg.c << endl << endl;
   cout << "Array\t\tValue\n";
   cout_bar(40);
   for (int i = 0; i < arg.c; i++)
   {
      cout << "argv[" << i << "]\t\t" << *arg.v[i] << endl;
   }
   return;
}
```

but when I call `*arg.v[i]` the program ends without printing the value of the second argument or any others for that matter.

So my question is,  is there some way I can use the struct to pass between functions such that I can call `arg.v[some_index < arg.c]` inside another function by somehow making the line `arg.v = argv` in main work as I had intended (to store the address of `argv` in `arg.v`)

All the structure does is make it so that instead of having to pass `argc` and `argv` to a function which has a decleration like: `void func(int &argc, char *argv[]);` I can instead pass my new structure type with variable name `arg` to a function declared like `void func(arguments &arg)` and that is basically all I wanted the structure for. So if I cannot do this, then I can go back to the first method.

Comment: Note that in a function declaration, `char *argv[]` and `char **argv` have the same meaning, and both mean "`argv` is a pointer to a pointer to a `char`".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write:

```
struct arguments
{
    int    c;
    char **v;
};
```

Now your `main()` will work.  (And this sort of confusion is why I always use `int main(int argc, char **argv)`, but that's a personal quirk.)

If you were working in C99 or later, what you created with your structure is what is called a ['flexible array member'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804398/the-difference-of-the-pointer-and-a-array/13804535#13804535) (FAM), an addition to C99 over C89 (and therefore over C++98).  I didn't notice that you're working in C++!  There are special rules about FAM in C, and you can't do the assignment as you did with a flexible array member.

However, the fix will work in C++ just as much as in C; it is just not necessarily correct that you're using an FAM.  Are you using a C++ compiler that supports FAM as an extension?

In your output line, you have:

```
cout << "argv[" << i << "]\t\t" << *arg.v[i] << endl;
```

That would print the first character of the argument; drop the `*` and you'd get the first argument as a string:

```
cout << "argv[" << i << "]\t\t" << arg.v[i] << endl;
```

Comment: Yes, let me edit my question to be more clear why I do not understand why I cannot then call *arg.v[1]

Comment: and C++ is not compatible with c99, we still do not have VLAs in C++

Comment: @Aniket: Yes...interesting; I assumed it was C99 because of the FAM...and FAM does not work in C++, does it?  Or is that new in C++2011?

Comment: Nope, not yet in C++ afaik - maybe it will be in the future, but for now, its not there. Maybe people will say - why not use `std::vector` instead of a FAM, but those madmen in C++ standards community may come up with absolutely anything and the kitchen sink

Comment: There is still a problem here, if I pass arg to a function like `argument_reader` in my question, how do I call `*arg.v[i]` when I use this in `cout` I am expecting it to print the full argument, not a single character.

Comment: ` *arg.v[i] ` should be `argv[i]`. @Leonardo

Comment: I am not sure if it supports FAM, but it compiles with either CodeBlocks and MinGW without any flags so maybe it does?

Comment: The only error I can provoke from GCC (4.6.0) is: `error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘char**’ to ‘char* [0]’`.  I suppose that means that G++ is treating the declaration as a zero-length array, which is an extension AFAIK (but `g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++98 -pedantic` only complains about the assignment, not about the empty array in the structure definition.

Answer (score 3):

Change your struct to this:

```
struct arguments
{
   int c;
   char **v;
};
```

C-style array and pointer are very similar, and you can use above struct just like your version or the original `argv` parameter.

Indeed, often main function is declared like that instead of using []:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

Note that with this answer code `v` points to the original `argv` array of pointers to char, pointers are not copied. If you actually want a copy, you need to dynamically allocate array of char pointers and copy.

Answer (score 1):

two things:

```
struct arguments
{
   int c;
   char *v[]; /*unknown length, hence structure is incomplete*/
};
```

You need a double pointer, which holds the address of the `argv`

```
    struct arguments {
       int c;
       char **v;
    };
```

Comment: That makes sense, that it does not know the length of the array is probably why I cannot call `*arg.v[1]`, thanks that is a clear answer.